# Two row header for Get-ADObject | Export-Csv?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

An external system we use requires an import of an excel template. The data that is being imported can be derived from Active Directory data.

I am building a one-click solution in PowerShell 2.0 that builds this template out with current Active Directory data.

The current process I am using is `Get-ADObject > select and do some reformating | Export-Csv`.

The template I am trying to replicate has two header rows. `Export-Csv` only provides one header, based on the field name (I actually used `Select-Object @{Label=,Expression=}` to customize the ADObject property names).

How can I add another header row? Can I append an entry to the beginning of each ADObject property?

```
Header 1
Entry1
Entry2
Entry3
```

to

```
Header 1
Header 2
Entry1
Entry2
Entry3
```

Comment: Take a look at `PSCustomObjects`: https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/

Comment: I've used them before. What I'm asking is how I can append an entry to the beginning of the property list (like an additional header), because $property = "Header" + $property concatenates "header" to the beginning of each string entry.

Maybe something like Property.Add("Header"); Property.add(list of values)?

Comment: Just insert a custom object with your secondary headers as the values of properties named after the primary headers at the beginning of your data.

Comment: Can I append two custom objects and export to the same csv? I think I recall export-csv has an -append parameter? Maybe? Will test

Comment: That’s about as close as I got conceptually. But I don’t believe I can append two PSCustomObjects on indentical properties, not can I export two objects to the same csv file, with the second object printing on the next row in column A. I’ll have to look through the export-csv reference to see if there is an -append parameter. If not, it overwrites the existing content on the second write

Comment: `Export-Csv` has a `-Append` parameter since at least since PowerShell v3. And you can always do `$($obj1; $obj2; $list) | Export-Csv ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just duplicate to 2nd header?

```
Get-ADObject | Select-Object Header1,@{label='Header2';expression=$_.Header1}
```

Or if it needs to be in same row:

```
$Data = Get-ADObject | additional piping
$Data.Header1 += 'Header2'
$Data | Export-CSV
```

Or you are trying to add Property

```
$Data = Get-ADObject | additional piping
[PSCustomObject]$NewData = $Data
$NewData | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'MyProperty' -Value 'myvalue'
$NewData | Export-CSV
```

Comment: The headers are across all the other fields I am pulling from AD. Your first solution just adds the headers as columns. And yes, they need to be two distinct rows to be read correctly

Comment: Perhaps I should clarify. Header 1 aren’t a property themselves. They are the names of the properties I’m pulling from the ADObject. I need to add a second header row, but as I cannot give properties two distinct names, I need to somehow add an entry to each of these properties with the Header2 value.

Comment: i updated my answer to give a 3rd example, perhaps this is what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up getting what I wanted, by first converting my AD Object into a Custom object and creating second custom object with the same fields, but my headers as values. Threw them both into an array, and it writes beautifully.

```
$ad = Get-AdObject...
$obj1 = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -property $ad

$hash = @{
    'col1'='header1';
    'col2'='header2';
     ...
}
$obj2 = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -property $hash

$arr1 = @()
$arr1 += $obj2, $obj1
$arr1 | Export-csv -path...
```